# getting source code for linux's /bin/ss tool

Tags: c, linux, netstat, netlink, ss

`ss` tool is analogue to `netstat`. ss uses NETLINK libraries documented really bad (`man 7 netlink`). I couldn't find online how properly use NETLINK_INET_DIAG feature. Source code for ss tool would help, but I can't find it either. Any advice would be really appreciated.

```
root@ubuntu:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

root@ubuntu:~# apt-get source ss
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for ss
```

Comment: You can run `dpkg -S /bin/ss` to get the name of the package that owns this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package that you are searching for is: [`iproute`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/iproute)

Try `apt-get source iproute` instead. You will find the source code in `misc/ss.c`.

*NOTE: You can use the [ubuntu packages search tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and go to "Search the contents of packages"*

Comment: You can also use `dpkg -S /bin/ss`.